# What is a statistical test to quantify the probability of random success?

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

This might be a trivial question, but I am not deeply familiar with standard statistical methods in descriptive statistics.

I'm conducting the following experiment:

1. The subject receives a stimuli in one of 6 locations on their body.
2. They have to enter the location of the stimuli on a keypad. So in the end, a response is either correct or incorrect.

My goal is to reason about setting a threshold value for the mean success rate of all subjects. I'm thinking that if the subject has a success rate of n from N (say 16/20 = 80%), the probability that they achieved that randomly is so low that it could not have been due to randomly selecting answers, and use that as a threshold. Is this valid? What is a statistical test appropriate for this situation?

Obviously, the most extreme is when the subject chooses all responses randomly. But how can I also consider the effect of the case where the subject might have chosen 1 or 2 or 3 responses at random?

Note: Each location is stimulated 24 times. The sequence of stimulation is random. There are 6 subjects.

Comment: The answer depends on the number of stimuli, the sequence in which they are presented, the relative frequencies of the six locations, and the number of subjects.  Could you provide that information?

Comment: Added that information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I can just summarize before giving my answer:

- Each subject is observed 24 times
- The location of the stimulus can change but we observe the same location several times within subjects.
- Your goal is to estimate the probability that the subject selects the correct location of the stimulus

Have I understood that correctly?

Because you are modelling a binary variable (correct or incorrect) as a function of location of the stimulus location, and because you observe the same person multiple times, I'm thinking a mixed effects logistic regression might be appropriate.